# "Expires" attribute points to a date in the past

Tags: cookies, struts2, jboss

I'm trying to set a cookies for my site. I'm using:

```
ServletActionContext.getResponse().addCookie(<my cookie instance>);
```

Cookie maxAge is set to "2592000". However... for some unknown reason header looks like this:

```
Server:Wildfly 8
Set-Cookie:LOCALE=en_GB; path=/scores;
    Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Mon, 02-Jun-2014 19:17:54 GMT
```

Today is according to the header:

```
Date:Sun, 22 Jun 2014 12:20:41 GMT
```

, so I'm surprised why "Expires" field date points to a date in the past. I'm completely out of ideas. I would be grateful for any hints. Maybe I need to configure something?

Edit:
Here's my method for creating my cookies:

```
public Cookie getCookie(final String name, final String value, final int maxAge, final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    final Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value); 
    cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge); 
    cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath()); 
    cookie.setSecure(false); 
    return cookie;
}
```

Edit2:
I've just noticed there's a difference between header format sent to the browser when using Jboss 7. There's no Max-age present - just calculated (and correct) Expiry time.

```
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Set-Cookie:LOCALE=en_GB; Expires=Tue, 22-Jul-2014 13:44:00 GMT; Path=/scores
```

It seems Jboss 8 Wildfly should be configured somehow to calculate cookies expiry time.  Unfortunately I have to use Wildfly.

Comment: Show how do you create a cookie instance.

Comment: Nothing special here:
        final Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
        cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);
        cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        return cookie;

Comment: Don't post a code in comments, edit a question to provide details. Doing that for better help, sooner prepare [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still wasting my time (I've lost 8h today) trying to fix that but... I've got a workaround (which could help someone in the future) and an interesting fact.

The line of code looking like this:

```
 ServletActionContext.getResponse().addCookie(newInstance(name, value, maximumAge, request));
```

I've replaced by this:

```
protected void set(final String name, final String value, final long maximumAgeInSeconds, final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    // ServletActionContext.getResponse().addCookie(newInstance(name, value, maximumAgeInSeconds, request));
    ServletActionContext.getResponse().addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieValue(name, value, maximumAge, request));
}
protected static String cookieValue(final String name, final String value, final long maximumAgeInSeconds, final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    final SimpleDateFormat cookieExpiresHeaderFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    cookieExpiresHeaderFormat.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT"));
    final Date d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + maximumAgeInSeconds * 1000L);
    final String cookieLifeTime = cookieExpiresHeaderFormat.format(d);
    return name + "=" + value + "; Expires=" + cookieLifeTime + "; Max-Age=" + maximumAge + "; Path=" + request.getContextPath();
}
```

That one works fine, and it seems I've found a bug in Jboss 8, or... whatever library which converts cookies into headers. 
If maxAgeInSeconds variable equals to 30 days, converted into miliseconds 2592000*1000=2592000000 overlaps MAX_INT (which is 2147483647) so it's value became "-1702967296"!!!!

Example:

current time: 1403460809297 - 1702967296 = (in seconds) 1401757842

Which is:
GMT: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 01:10:42 GMT

That's why I'm receiving Expiry date from the past. It just seems a mechanism converting Cookie object Max-Age attribute into "Expires" attribute of a Cookie header using INTeger instead of wider Long type accidentally setting cookie Expiry date from the past. 
Interesting fact is that problem applies to IE but not Chrome for example which uses Max-age for internal Expiry time calculations omitting Expiry time from the Cookie. IE in this case omits Max-Age attribute value taking already calculated Expires attribute value for received Cookies.